# I cant open folders as root

Tags: 14.04, themes, root, directory

When I try to open the themes folder using this command

> gksu nautilus /usr/share/themes

this is what the system throws back at me

> (nautilus:21515): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from 'GtkMessageDialog' to 'NautilusWindow'
>   **
>   ERROR:nautilus-window.c:2116:nautilus_window_get_slots: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_WINDOW (window))

Maybe I'm not typing the right command, please help, I can't access my folders as root...

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one to experience this problem on 14.04.

Here is a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1309254

And here is a forum thread where people claim to have solved it: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2216553

Although I can't really see a good solution in that thread - "install samba" seems crazy.  The last post in that thread literally says:

> The thing that solved it for me, was to install "Samba"

It's probably not samba itself that resolves this but it just so happens to be one of its dependencies.